# ImportError: cannot import name sqlContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, importerror, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark to read some csv data to spark Dataframe.

I try to import pyspark module as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import sqlContext
```

Why do I get the following error? How to fix it?

> ImportError: cannot import name sqlContext

I'm using Python 2.7 and Spark 2.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you don't have your python pat set correctly. I find the following function useful when configuring my python environments.

```
def configure_spark(spark_home=None, pyspark_python=None, conf_dir=None):
    """Configures the Python path for importing pyspark

    Sets the SPARK_HOME and PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variables and modifies
    the Python PATH so the pyspark package can be imported.

    Args:
        spark_home (str): Path of SPARK_HOME. Defaults to SPARK_HOME module
            variable.
        pyspark_python (str): Path to Python binary to use in PySpark. Defaults
            to the currently executing Python binary.
        conf_dir (str): Path to configuration directory
    """

    # Set the configuration directory with some basic sanity checks:
    if conf_dir:
        if not os.path.isdir(conf_dir):
            raise OSError("Spark config directory not found: %s" % conf_dir)

        expected_conf = {'spark-env.sh', 'spark-defaults.conf'}
        found_conf = expected_conf - set(os.listdir(conf_dir))
        if found_conf:
            warnings.warn("Some configuration files were not found: %s" % found_conf)

        os.environ['SPARK_CONF_DIR'] = conf_dir

    spark_home = spark_home or SPARK_HOME
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_home

    if not os.path.isdir(spark_home):
        raise OSError("Specified SPARK_HOME is not a valid directory: %s" % spark_home)

    # Add the PySpark directories to the Python path:
    libs = glob(os.path.join(spark_home, 'python', 'lib', '*.zip'))
    if len(libs) < 2:
        raise OSError("Pyspark libraries not found in %s" % spark_home)
    for lib in libs:
        sys.path.insert(1, lib)

    # If PYSPARK_PYTHON isn't specified, use currently running Python binary:
    pyspark_python = pyspark_python or sys.executable
    os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = pyspark_python
```

Comment: @Don't know why you have no upvote, this function is amazing, did you write it yourself ?

Comment: @Tbaki I did, yes, because I ended up running into this issue so many times. I'm actually shocked that it's not in the pyspark code. Maybe they've added it by now.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but this should be given to every person trying to install pyspark, saved me from all the trouble i've got with other method. Thanks a lot for your  method, i'll be sure to recomand it around me ! But not sure how to give it the attention it deserve. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using just pyspark, I have the same issue in my Jupyter Notebook you can resolve using

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
```